# Aliasing a FOR XML PATH result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to alias the output of the following:

```
-- Test table with some rubbish data
DECLARE @Test TABLE
(
    Names [varchar](20)
)
INSERT INTO @Test
SELECT 'Simon'

-- Query returns but with XML_<GUID> alias
SELECT 
    Names
FROM 
    @Test t 
FOR XML PATH ('Test')
```

So rather than a column header of XML_GUID I want to give it an alias of say 'Test' for sake of argument. I can't seem to get it. Anyone know how? I tried following an example from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sqlxml/thread/1605c722-6388-40ff-9ab5-a3817a1db81f but I can't seem to get it to return. I always run into the error that says the is no name for column 1.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose returned column name in a SELECT FOR XML query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304940/how-to-choose-returned-column-name-in-a-select-for-xml-query)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make it a subquery:

```
select (
SELECT 
    Names
FROM 
    @Test t 
FOR XML PATH ('Test'),TYPE) as Test
```

Subqueries produce values but never provide a name for a column. I also specified `,TYPE` because otherwise it forces a conversion to `varchar(max)` on the result, whereas you presumably want to keep it as `xml`.

Comment: What if I have multiple columns in my select list?