# Change the column name for the selected column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the selected column as InspectionReportId. While executing the below query the output and the column name is not properly shown.

```
 SELECT
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Id) + '~' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 19021) + '|' AS InspectionReportId
 FROM 
     OBJ_SystemPanelInspectionReports  
 WHERE
     SystemId = 19021  
 FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: @Dev Try have you tried with `(..) AS col_name`

Comment: @YogeshSharma    select  CONVERT(varchar(100), Id) + '~' +CONVERT(varchar(100), 19021) +'|'    data as InspectionReportId

Comment: Are you simply losing upper/lower case? Then `AS [InspectionReportId]` should do. SQL Server uses the non-standard brackets, while Standard SQL uses double quotes.

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi   Yeah.. I tried

Comment: @DevTry shw error wht u getting, because it would be work.

Comment: You want column name of the SQL table shown in SSMS as InspectionReportId, or you want your nodes to be named like that.

Comment: "not properly shown" is a very poor description. Why have us guess instead of telling us how the column name is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Found on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379902/aliasing-a-for-xml-path-result)

You can surround your statement by `SELECT ( ... ) AS [YourColumnName]`

```
SELECT (
SELECT
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Id) + '~' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), 19021) + '|' AS InspectionReportId
 FROM 
     OBJ_SystemPanelInspectionReports  
 WHERE
     SystemId = 19021  
 FOR XML PATH ('')
) AS [YourColumnName]
```